# Hibernate falsely treats entities as immutable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We are using Hibernate 3.3.2/Spring 3.0.5 in our application and one of the server modules still utilizes the old `HibernateTemplate`/`HibernateDaoSupport` classes.
I've been trying to remove these since I have to implement our own transaction logic in this module.
The problem is, if I access the session directly instead of using HibernateTemplate, Hibernate acts as if all entities have the `@Immutable` annotation: I can create new database entries and delete these or old ones, but I cannot update existing entries anymore.

I have narrowed the problem down to `DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush`, where `source.getPersistenceContext().hasNonReadOnlyEntities()` always returns `false` in that case, but I could not find out yet why this flag is wrongly set.
I have also verified that none of the entities is really annotated as `@Immutable`, or is actively set to readonly anywhere using `Query.setReadOnly` or `Session.setReadOnly`.

Worse, setting `readonly=false` anywhere also has no effect, the entity stays immutable.

In our other server modules, we have never used `HibernateTemplate`/`HibernateDaoSupport` and these work fine with all CRUD operations.

This is the code using the old Hibernate classes:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
public class GenericHibernateDAO<T, PK extends Serializable> extends HibernateDaoSupport implements GenericDAO <T, PK>
{
    @Override
    public Serializable create(final T instance)
    {
        return this.getHibernateTemplate().save(instance);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(final T instance)
    {
        this.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(instance);
    }

    @Override
    public T findById(final Class <T> clazz, final PK id)
    {
        return this.getHibernateTemplate().get(clazz, id);
    }

    ...
}
```

This is how I modified it, and how it works in our other modules:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
public class GenericHibernateDAO<T, PK extends Serializable> implements GenericDAO <T, PK>
{
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return this.sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(final SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session getSession()
    {
        return SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(this.sessionFactory, true);
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable create(final T instance)
    {
        return this.getSession().save(instance);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(final T instance)
    {
        this.getSession().saveOrUpdate(instance);
    }

    @Override
    public T findById(final Class <T> clazz, final PK id)
    {
        return (T) this.getSession().get(clazz, id);
    }
    ...
}
```

Definition of derived DAO class:

```
public class RepositoryFolderHibernateDAO extends GenericHibernateDAO <RepositoryFolder, Long> implements RepositoryFolderDAO
```

Entity definition:

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "repositoryfolder") 
public class RepositoryFolder
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "repository_id", nullable = false)
    private long repositoryId = 1L;

    @Column(name = "parent_id", nullable = true)
    private Long parent;

    @Column(length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 255, nullable = true)
    private String description;

    @Cascade(value =
    { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.folderId")
    private Set <MandatorFolderRight> mandatorFolderRights = new HashSet <MandatorFolderRight>();

    public RepositoryFolder()
    {
        super();
    }

        ... more c'tors and getters/setters
}
```

Using `HibernateDao` + `HibernateTemplate` all updates are executed, but without they are ignored and just create and delete operations work.
I've been searching for days but could not find any reason for this strange behavior. Bean definitions are also the same in both cases.

Has anyone else ever had this problem and found a solution?

Comment: Don't use `SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(this.sessionFactory, true)` but rather use `this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` instead. If that fails with an error your transaction setup is borked.

Comment: We only use the `@Transactional` annotation so far (code updated).
What's wrong with `SessionFactoryUtils.getSession`? Even `HibernateTemplate` internally calls this function and it works fine in our other modules.
When I use `getCurrentSession()` I'm in fact getting an exception saying than `createQuery()` does not work without a transaction.

Comment: Which means your tx or hibernate configuration is wrong. There is a whole lot going on in the `HibernateTemplate` what it does depends highly on your configuration. What is wrong with the other solution is that you get a `Session` outside the scope of the current transaction. So it will never commit/flush changes to the database. So whatever you do in that session is basically in-memory only. It is also dangerous as eventually you will run out of connections because you are keep opening session without closing them.